# can u help me with this simple html code?

Tags: html, css, tags

I have an h1 element in HTML **"THE COOL THE MINIMAL"** How to change **"THE COOL"** text color to green and **"THE MINIMAL"** text color to white. I am a beginner ty for help.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Note that SO is not a Tutorial or Guide. It is expected, that you have done sufficient research efford and at least tried to solve an issue on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can split the word into 2 and append them into the span tag and give the span tag a class of whatever property you want

```
<style>
 .green-color {
  color: green
   }
  .white-color {
  color: white
   }
</style>

  <h1><span class="green-color">THE COOL</span> <span class="white-color">THE MINIMAL</span></h1>
```

Comment: code only answers can be considered low-quality. they miss a sufficient explaination to be understood and reproduced. Beside of that, in 2021 inline style is the wrong approach to start with unless you need it for e-mail templating.